# Flash AS2: How to POST CDATA to a server?

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2, cdata

I have an XML object that I want to send to my player via HTTP POST. This is all good when using XML.sendAndLoad.

The problem is that when the XML object I generate contains CDATA, the CDATA is stripped out before the POST occurs.

so if I have:

```
var xml:XML = new XML("<root><tag><![CDATA[hello]]></tag></root>")
```

when I do a sendAndLoad this is what gets POSTed:

```
<root><tag>hello</tag></root>
```

the same occurs when I try to create the XML using XMLDOM methods like createElement, createTextNode, and appendChild.

the AS2 docs say that CDATA is not supported. Is there a workaround for this? I'm thinking that it could be fixed by extending and overriding the XML class, but I haven't found a way to do it yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. CDATA is substituted by the XML parser at the time it builds its tree. What is sent is a serialization of the tree, sans the CDATA.

If you want to send raw XML source you have to send it as pure string data.

BTW I fail to see how it can be a problem here, since both are semantically identical, i.e. "<![CDATA[hello]]>" and "hello" give the same string. CDATA is just a quoting syntax, not significant markup. However there can be a problem if the CDATA contains special characters. You will have to quote them properly.

Comment: problem is that the script on the server (i didn't build it) is looking for CDATA. How can I send RAW XML source? I can'y do it with LoadVars since that attaches a var name and that's another thing that the server-side script won't allow.

Comment: The server script is at fault here. Unfortunately I don't see how it can be worked around.

As a last resort, try to escape the CDATA delimiters, e.g. ">![CDATA[hello]]<", or setting xml.contentType to 'text/xml'.

Comment: Oops I meant <![CDATA[hello]]>