# how to post XML as value for HTML input element

Tags: c#, html, xml

I have to submit a `HTTP POST` request using a standard HTML Form element that contains one HTML input element which will contain the request XML.

This is the current code that I am trying with :

```
<form id="{CustomFormID}" method="post" name="{CustomFormName}" action="{TestHarness.aspx}">
<input type="text" id="inputData" name="inputData" value="{Request XML}"/>
```

I have created a function on `Page_Load` to build the request XML. The thing I want to know is, how can I pass that XML value through here.

Suggestions and hints are appreciated.

Comment: I have converted XML to String.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the built XML with `CData` and use that in hidden field and post to required aspx page.

Syntax - `<![CDATA[XML_VALUE]]>`, replace XML_VALUE with actuals.

Similar answer posted here - [Flash AS2: How to POST CDATA to a server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439747/flash-as2-how-to-post-cdata-to-a-server)

Comment: I have converted the XML to string.

Comment: Yes, that won't be any issue, the above answer is to ensure that receiving end gets XML value instead of string.

Comment: i tried to do that 'string parsedXMl = "<![CDATA[{0}]]>";

        requestXML = string.Format(parsedXMl, BuildXML("Dummy"));' but it throws A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (formInput="        <![CDATA[<WEB_INTEGR..."). does that mean only first line is getting passed